# How to paste text and variables into a logical expression in R?

Tags: r, paste

I want to paste variables in the logical expression that I am using to subset data, but the subset function does not see them as column names when pasted (either with ot without quotes).

I have a dataframe with columns named col1, col2 etc. I want to subset for the rows in which colx < 0.05

This DOES work:

```
subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, col1<0.05)

subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, col2<0.05)
```

This does NOT work:

```
for (k in 1:2){
subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, paste("col",k,sep="")<0.05)
}

for (k in 1:2){
subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, noquote(paste("col",k,sep=""))<0.05)
}
```

I can't find the answer; any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options that are closer to the Jasper's approach. First, you could define the column name as a separate variable and then use it to select the variable from the `data.frame` as if it were a `list` (since a `data.frame` is basically a `list`):

```
for(k in 1:2){
  colname <- paste("col",k,sep="")
  subsetdata <- dataframe[dataframe[[colname]] < 0.05, ]
}
```

Or you could refer to the column name as such:

```
  subsetdata <- dataframe[dataframe[colname,] < 0.05, ]
```

Finally, you could use `subset`, although you need to provide a logical expression (as pointed out by Joshua Ulrich):

```
  subsetdata <- subset(dataframe, eval(substitute(x < 0.05, list(x = as.name(colname)))))
```

Comment: Thansk Nullglob! And thanks for spelling out how to pass and evaluate the variable into subset!

Answer (score 9):

You're making this a lot harder than it needs to be by trying to use `subset`.  Note that `?subset` says the second argument (also named subset) must be an expression and you're not giving it an expression:

```
> is.expression(paste("col",1:2,sep="")<0.05)
[1] FALSE
```

You could construct an unevaluated expression then evaluate it as you pass it to `subset`, but there are much easier ways.  For example: just take advantage of the vectorized nature of the `<` operator.

```
# sample data
set.seed(21)
dataframe <- data.frame(col1=rnorm(10),col2=rnorm(10),col3=1)

logicalCols <- dataframe[,paste("col",1:2,sep="")] < 0.05
#        col1  col2
#  [1,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [2,] FALSE FALSE
#  [3,] FALSE  TRUE
#  [4,]  TRUE FALSE
#  [5,] FALSE FALSE
#  [6,] FALSE FALSE
#  [7,]  TRUE FALSE
#  [8,]  TRUE FALSE
#  [9,] FALSE  TRUE
# [10,]  TRUE  TRUE
ANY <- apply(logicalCols, 1, any)  # any colx < 0.05
ALL <- apply(logicalCols, 1, all)  # all colx < 0.05
dataframe[ANY,]
dataframe[ALL,]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear to me what you're trying to do but perhaps seeing `&` and `|` used in a `subset` operation would be helpful.

Both `col1` and `col2` less than 0.05:

```
subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, col1 < 0.05 & col2 < 0.05)
```

Either `col1` or `col2` less than 0.05:

```
subsetdata<-subset(dataframe, col1 < 0.05 | col2 < 0.05)
```

Joshua's answer is a great way of doing this more easily over many columns.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, I need to paste in the variable for for-looping over many different column combis (for which indeed I can use Joshua's answer).